# check only once on click event with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

On every click i tried to check if the class exists, and if the class found then load the `enscroll` plugin.
but the problem is, after find the class `st2-wr || st2`, its again load the enscroll plugin with click event because the class exists,

i want only once the plugin load after finding the class.

```
$('.embtn').delegate(this, 'click', function(){
    var $sec = $(this).closest('.sec'), 
        $parentSection = $sec.closest('.m_ms');

    if($parentSection.hasClass('st2-wr') || $parentSection.hasClass('st2')){
        $('.ms_box').enscroll({
                 showOnHover: true,
                 verticalTrackClass: 'track3',
                 verticalHandleClass: 'handle3'
         });
     }
});
```

Comment: which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: @roasted 1.9.1 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible snippet if i understood your goal:

```
$('.embtn').on('click', function () {
    var $sec = $(this).closest('.sec'),
        $parentSection = $sec.closest('.m_ms');

    if (!$('.ms_box').data('enscroll') && ($parentSection.hasClass('st2-wr') || $parentSection.hasClass('st2'))) {
        $('.ms_box').enscroll({
            showOnHover: true,
            verticalTrackClass: 'track3',
            verticalHandleClass: 'handle3'
        }).data('enscroll', true);

    }
});
```

Comment: is there any specific reason behind using `.on()` instead of `.delegate()`??

Comment: no, and here using .on() my code is wrong. I updated as .on() delegation accept only 'selector'. .on() is just the new alias for bind/delegate & live, for consistency

Comment: sorry for wrong order of params using delegate, updated answer and i need coffee :)

Comment: :) ofcause, but one more thing, i didn't tried before the `.data()` method, but it's not working, i thing the possible reason is, i already used the enscroll() plugin on page load on other element, and this the second time that i want to use on the different element?? is this the reason of not working this code?

Comment: OOPPS a big mistake by me.. the code is working @rasted :), thankks

Comment: your welcome, data() here is just use as a boolean flag, it's better than setting it like this than using instead a global variable, hope you got the idea

Comment: @roasted Nice solution, why not using `.on()` method if jQuery version is 1.9.1, instead of `.delegate()`?

Comment: Because .on() method only support string as selector. I never use delegate() method but in fact, as i've just checked in doc, this is the same for delegate, it's only accept string as selector. In fact here, OP is making a mistake, using delegate as it is simple bind method. He could change is code to use bind/on without any change but for clarity i let it as it. e.g $('.embtn').on('click', function () {...}); would work the same here. Sorry, i know i'm not very clear with this comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method

```
$("#foo").one("click", function() {
  alert("This will be displayed only once.");
});
```

Other way is to use some external boolean variable that will tell you if the plugin has been loaded.

Comment: one() method doesn't support delegation

Comment: @nKognito `The handler is executed at most once per element.- one()`, i am using the click event on a button, that have to press more then once..

Comment: @jogesh_pi Other way is to use some external boolean variable that will tell you if the plugin has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(self) {
    function enscroll() {
        var $sec = $(this).closest('.sec'), 
            $parentSection = $sec.closest('.m_ms');

        if($parentSection.hasClass('st2-wr') || $parentSection.hasClass('st2')){
            $('.ms_box').enscroll({
                showOnHover: true,
                verticalTrackClass: 'track3',
                verticalHandleClass: 'handle3'
            });
            $('.embtn').off('click', self, enscroll);
        }
    }
    $('.embtn')
        .on('click', self, enscroll)
        .on('click', self, function() {
            // Other click handler executed each time
        });
})(this);
```

Comment: Maybe better because the click handler will be executed once and the dom tree browsed (closest) once too...